mapping torus is a smooth manifold
My question: Let $M$ be a closed smooth n-manifold, $\varphi \in Diff(M)$. Prove that the mapping torus $T_{\varphi}(M) = M \times [0, 1] / \sim$ is a smooth manifold, where $(x, 0) \sim (\varphi(x), 1)$ for any $x \in M$.
My attempt: Since $M$ is a compact manifold, we can choose a finite atlas $\{(U_{j}, f_{j}) | j = 1, \dots, n\}$. For $M \times (0, 1)$, it is straightforward to consider taking $V_{j} = U_{j} \times (0, 1)$ and $h_{j} = f_{j} \times Id_{(0, 1)}$. For $M \times \{0\} \cup M \times \{1\} / \sim$, consider taking $W_{j} = ((U_{j} \cap \varphi^{-1}(U_{j})) \times [0, \varepsilon)) \cup ((U_{j} \cap \varphi^{-1}(U_{j})) \times (1 - \varepsilon, 1]) / \sim$. However, how do I prove that $W_{j}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}$ and that the new charts form an atlas? It seems somewhat obvious, but I am unsure how to rigorously prove it.

One way to prove such results is to consider the action of infinite cyclic group generated by $(x,t)\mapsto (\varphi(x), t+1)$ on $M\times \mathbb R$. Then check that this is a smooth covering action and the quotient is naturally homeomorphic to $T_\varphi(M)$.

Define $W_j = U_j \cap \phi^{-1}_{j}(U_j)$, as you mentioned above, you have a (bijective) continuous map $\psi_j: W_j \times [0,\epsilon) \cup W_j \times (1-\epsilon, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$. This map preserves the equivalence classes and by the universal property of quotient topology it descends to a continuous homeomorphism: $$\tilde{\psi_j}: (W_j \times [0,\epsilon) \cup W_j \times (1-\epsilon, 1] )/\sim \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$$
This already proves the mapping torus is a topological manifold (provided you proved/understand it is hausdorff and second countable) At this point it suffices to prove that the transition maps for overlapping charts (as previously constructed) are smooth.
